# Codeigniter weird ajax result in controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've started a codeigniter project and now a i have to do an ajax call to a special controller.

It goes something like this:
- I have two select fields: 1 for selecting county's and the other one must populate with the city's in the selected county.

The problem is I get a really weird result when I send the selected county id to the ajax controller.

If I put something like this in the controller : echo "a $county_id" in the controller it will give me the response : a [selected county_id], but if I only echo out the county id it shows some json empty response, and I don't know what's wrong, below is the code:

1. the ajax(jquery) call.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#judet').change(function(){
               var county = $( "select option:selected" ).val();

               $.ajax({
                   type:'POST',
                   /*dataType: "json",*/
                   data:{cou_county:county},
                   url:'<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/") ?>',
                   success:function(){
                       console.log('id_judet:' + county);
                   },
                   error:function(mesaj){
                       console.log("there's an error");
                   }
               });
           });

       });
   ```
2. The codeigniter ajax_controller Controller:

   ```
       public function index()
       {       header('content-type text/html charset=utf-8');
           $cou_county = $this->input->post('cou_county');
           $decodedCounty = $cou_county;
           echo "$decodedCounty";
       }
   ```

   The county and city selectors are two simple select inputs with id's I'll post some pictures if you think i haven't explained it well eneugh.

EDIT: the ajax call does access the controller, where i actually echo that id, but in the response i get some weird json thingy instead of the number, like in the picture below:

[the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs8T2.jpg)

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and thanks in advance to those of you who take the time to help a brother out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PHP code in javascript:

```
<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/") ?>
```

Instead, you should create a js variable like this:

```
base_url = '<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/") ?>';
```

Then use this variable with your function.

Comment: I saw some guy do it like that in a toturial, but noted i will change that, thanks!

Comment: Crate the variable inside php file, not inside javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `base_url()` you have to load url helper in controller like this..

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or load in `application/config/autoload.php`.

Then in your ajax edit `url` to

```
url:'<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/index");?>',
```

In controller:

```
public function index()
    {       
        $cou_county = $this->input->post('cou_county');
        echo $cou_county;
    }
```

In ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                /*dataType: "json",*/
                data:{cou_county:county},
                url:'<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/index");?>',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data); //see your console
                },
                error:function(data){
                    console.log("there's an error");
                }
            });
```